# Input polling in a while(true) loop on a different thread only working once

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, input, while-loop

I've created a stop watch app. Within its constructor I've started a new thread that has a `while(true)` loop to check for keyboard hits - if <kbd>Space</kbd> is hit the stopwatch will pause; if <kbd>A</kbd> is hit, the stopwatch resumes. This works once for each, however after that it does not register, and it seems the loop is no longer running or something because I put a log inside the `while` loop (but outside of the `if` statements) and it does not get printed every loop as I presumed it would. (Note I had to include `hasPressedSpace` and hasPressedA `booleans` because the Input events were being registered multiple times during one keystroke).

```
namespace StopWatch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
        }
    }

    public class StopWatch
    {
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; private set; }
        private bool _hasStoppped;
        private ThreadStart threadStart;
        private Thread thread;
        private bool isPaused;

        public StopWatch()
        {

            Duration = new TimeSpan();
            threadStart = new ThreadStart(KeyBoardThread);
            thread = new Thread(threadStart);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

        public void Start()
        {

            while (!_hasStoppped)
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Duration += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
                    Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + Duration);

                }
        }


        void KeyBoardThread()
        {

            bool hasPressedSpace = false;
            bool hasPressedA = false;

            while (true)
            {


            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Space) && !hasPressedSpace)
                {

                    hasPressedSpace = true;
                    hasPressedA = false;
                    Stop();
                }

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && !hasPressedA)
                {
                    hasPressedSpace = false;
                    hasPressedA = true;
                    _hasStoppped = false;
                    Start();
                }

            }


            }

         void Stop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("stop called");
            _hasStoppped = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you were using polling and not using an event driven approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to the end of your main function:

```
Console.WriteLine("Exit");
```

You will observe that after pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, the program prints "Exit". Then it, well, exits!

The problem is here:

```
while (!_hasStoppped)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Duration += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + Duration);
}
```

If `_hasStoppped` is `true` the thread completes and so does your program. You need to rethink your logic.

You may also like to note that a [`Stopwatch` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) is built into the .NET Framework :)

Comment: Hello thanks, I added a while(true) loop around the original while loop and it works. However I still don't understand how it didn't work before. If the main thread exits when _hasstoppped = true, then how could it still restart when hitting "A"  and then it does not take any more input?

Comment: @AdamJ Glad to hear my answer helped. You can Accept the answer by clicking the tick/check mark to the left of it, just under the up/down arrows. To answer your followup question: When you hit space you call `Stop()` which sets `_hasStoppped = true`. When you hit A you set `_hasStoppped = false`. Not sure about the second point - I would recommend using a .NET StopWatch and subscribing to Key events instead of your current approach.